# R: operations between vectors inside of lists and vectors outside

Tags: r, list, vector

Supose I have a list of 3 elements and each element is a list of 2 other elements. The first, a 4-dimensional vector and the second, say, a char. The following code will produce a list exactly as I just described it:

```
x <- NULL
for(i in 1:3){
  set.seed(i); a <- list(sample(1:4, 4, replace = T), LETTERS[i])
  x <- c(x, list(a))
}
```

Its structure is there fore of the following type (the exact values may chage since I used the sample function):

```
> str(x)
List of 3
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : int [1:4] 2 2 3 4
  ..$ : chr "A"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : int [1:4] 1 3 3 1
  ..$ : chr "B"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : int [1:4] 1 4 2 2
  ..$ : chr "C"
```

Now, I have an other 4-dimensional vector, say `y`:

```
y <- 1:4
```

Finally I want to create a matrix resulting from the operation (say sum) between `y` and each 4-dimensional vector stored in the list. For the given example, this matrix would give the following result:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    2    2
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    6    6    5
[4,]    8    5    6
```

**Question:** How can I create the above matrix in a simple and elegant way? I was searching for some solution that could use some `apply` function or that could use directly the `sum` function in some way that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @Zheyuan I guess there's no upside to setting the seed inside the loop (instead of outside).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
# you can also simply write: sapply(x, function(x) x[[1]]) + y
foo <- function(x)  x[[1]]
sapply(x, foo) + y
```

- The function `foo` extracts the vector inside the list;
- `sapply` returns those vectors as a matrix;
- Finally, we use recycling rule for addition.

---

**Update 1**

Well, since @Frank mentioned it. I might make a little explanation. The `'[['` operator in R (note the quote!) is a function, taking two arguments. The first is a vector type object, like a vector/list; while the second is the index which you want to refer to. For the following example:

```
a <- 1:4
a[2]  # 2
'[['(a, 2)  # 2
```

Though my original answer is easier to digest, it is not the most efficient, because for each list element, two function calls are invoked to take out the vector. While if we use `'[['` directly, only one function call is invoked. Therefore, we get time savings by reducing function call overhead. Function call overhead can be noticeable, when the function is small and does not do much work.

Operators in R are essentially functions. `+`, `*`, etc are arithmetic operators and you can find them by `?'+'`. Similarly, you can find `?'[['`. Don't worry too much if you can't follow this at the moment. Sooner or later you will get to it.

---

**Update 2**

> I don't understand how it actually does the job. When I simply ask for [[1]] at the console, I get the first element of the list (both the integer vector and the char value), not just the vector. I guess the remainder should be the magics of the `sapply` function.

Ah, if you have difficulty in understanding `sapply` (or similarly `lapply`), consider the following. But I will start from `lapply`.

`output <- lapply(x, foo)` is doing something like:

```
output <- vector("list", length = length(x))
for (i in 1:length(x)) output[[i]] <- foo(x[[i]])
```

So `lapply` returns a list:

```
> output
[[1]]
[1] 2 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 1 4 4 3

[[3]]
[1] 3 1 1 1
```

Yes, `lapply` loops through the elements of `x`, applying function `foo`, and return the result in another list.

`sapply` takes the similar idea, but returns a vector/matrix. You may think that `sapply` collapses the result of `lapply` to a vector/matrix.

Sure, my this part of explanation is just to make things understandable. `lapply` and `sapply` is not really implemented as R loop. They are more efficient.

Comment: Fyi, you don't need to write a full function definition `sapply(x, \`[[\`, 1)` works

Comment: @Zheyuan: thank you for such a complete answer. It works perfectly. Although I understand how it works - as you say, the function `foo` extracts the vector inside the list - I don't understand how it actually does the job. When I simply ask for `[[1]]` at the console, I get the first element of the list (both the integer vector and the char value), not just the vector. I guess the remainder should be the magics of the `sapply` function. I will accept your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Yes, I now understood whats happening under the hood and feel more confident using `sapply` and `lapply`. Great effort, great answer!